# JQuery Booklet Hash Only Works Once

Tags: jquery-plugins

I spotted a post ( [Jquery click function only fires once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12207586/jquery-click-function-only-fires-once) ) from someone experiencing a similar issue but I haven't been clever enough to ascertain whether or not the fix that was discovered can be applied to my problem; so I'm hoping that someone might be able to provide some more specific help?

I am having no joy whatsoever in trying to get the goto page stuff to fire more than once. I have the following in the head...

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function() {

    var mybook = $('#mybook').booklet();

    var hash = $(".selector").booklet( "option", "hash" );
    $(".selector").booklet( "option", "hash", true );

    $(function() {
        $('#mybook').booklet({
        closed: true,
        autoCenter: true
        });
    });

    });
</script>
```

Then for Page 6 I have…

```
    <div style="text-align: center" title="sixth page">
            <h3><a href="#/page/3">Go to page 3</a></h3>
        </div>
```

Clicking on the link works the first time around but never again thereafter. If anyone can offer any insights or steer me in the right direction I'll be eternally grateful.

I'm relatively inexperienced; so do please let me know if I haven't given enough detail, here. Many thanks :) x

Answer (score 0):

Hope this could help:

This is the Javascript:

```
$(function() {
   $('#mybook').booklet({
    closed: true,
   });

   $('#goto-page').click(function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
       $('#mybook').booklet("gotopage", "02");
       return false;
    });});
```

Change the number 02 to your desire page.

Here the html:

```
<div id="goto-page">
    <h3><a href="#">Jump to Page 2</a></h3>
</div>
```